# find, sort and extract a line from text files with bash

Tags: bash, sorting, sed, find, ls

I'm trying to make bash script that's a little bit too hard for me.
I need to search in directory for specific text files ending in "FA", sort the results alphabetically and take line 13 of each one and paste it into a new text file.

I read around and this is what I managed so far.
This command will search and sort the results:

```
find . -iname "*FA" -exec ls {} \; | sort
```

and it works fine.

This command will search and take line 13 of each file and paste it in a new file named "FACC.txt":

```
find . -iname "*FA" -exec sed -n 13p >FACC.txt {} \;
```

and it also works fine.

Now I need to combine the two, that is sort the results and take line 13 of each one!

Thank you! Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
find . -iname "*FA" -exec ls {} \; | sort | xargs -n 1 sed -n 13p
```

Comment: I don't what happened but instead of line 13 the above code gives me line 11 of each file ending in '*FA'

Comment: With the addition of >FACC.txt in the end, now is working perfectly!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: The `-exec ls {} \;` part is unneeded -- `find` prints the paths of matching files by default.

Comment: I preserved it, assuming we want the contents of the `*FA` dirs. Though I'd do it using `find` only as well.